# Tikz - parametrically set node text

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

I want to have a circle of nodes in tikz, and the text in each node needs to come from an array. How do I achieve this? The following does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{14}{21}\selectfont
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -stealth, thick]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={circle, text height=2ex, text depth=.25ex, text width=1.5em, text centered, draw=black!80, inner sep=0pt},>=stealth',auto,thick]
\def\names{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H}
\foreach \a in {1,2,...,8}{
\draw (\a*360/8: 4cm) node (\a) {\names[\a]};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is solved, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventhough you can use a two-variable loop (as you did in [`your answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261168/3954)), I'd also like to mention the possibility to work with just one variable and use the `count=<macro>` option (I also changed `\tikzstyle` for the more appropriate `\tikzset`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,}

\tikzset{
  line/.style={
    draw, 
    -stealth, 
    thick
  }
}    

\begin{document}

\fontsize{14}{21}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={
    circle, 
    text height=2ex, 
    text depth=.25ex, 
    text width=1.5em, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black!80, 
    inner sep=0pt
    },
  >=stealth',
  auto,
  thick
]
\foreach \t [count=\a] in {A,...,H}
{
  \draw (\a*360/8: 4cm) node (\a) {\t};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Done with a new array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{14}{21}\selectfont
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -stealth, thick]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={circle, text height=2ex, text depth=.25ex, text width=1.5em, text centered, draw=black!80, inner sep=0pt},>=stealth',auto,thick]
\foreach \a/\t in {1/A,2/B,3/C,4/D,5/E,6/F,7/G,8/H}{
\draw (\a*360/8: 4cm) node (\a) {\t};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```